# using @media for screens

Tags: html, css

Please i need help with this code

https://codepen.io/declareola/pen/XWWOyyK
    here is the code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: aqua;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
}

.column1 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 50px 2px 0px 5px;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: brown;
}

.column2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 50px 2px 0px 5px;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}

.column3 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 50px 2px 0px 5px;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: magenta;
}

.column4 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px #089c2d;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

@media(min-width:1200px) {
  .column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
  }
  .column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
  }
  .column3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
  }
}

@media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
  .column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .column3 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991) {
  .column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .column3 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>OUR MENU</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column1"><span class="column4">CHICKEN</span> Kirk this too will increase his shoes God give us Christian homes! Homes where the Bible is loved and taught, Homes where the Master’s will is sought, Homes crowned with beauty Your love has wrought; God give us
    Christian homes; God give us Christian homes! God give us Christian homes! Homes where the father is true and strong, Homes that are free from the blight of wrong, Homes that are joyous with love and song; God give us Christian homes; God give us
    Christian homes! God give us Christian homes! will audio policies school but thought office thing this offer still it's still think Rashi idea will</div>
  <div class="column2"><span class="column4">SUSHI</span>Colleen Kirk this too will increase his shoes God give us Christian homes! Homes where the Bible is loved and taught, Homes where the Master’s will is sought, Homes crowned with beauty Your love has wrought; God give
    us Christian homes; God give us Christian homes! God give us Christian homes! Homes where the father is true and strong, Homes that are free from the blight of wrong, Homes that are joyous with love and song; God give us Christian homes; God give
    us Christian homes! God give us Christian homes! will audio policies school but thought office thing this offer still it's still think Rashi idea will</div>
  <div class="column3"><span class="column4">BEEF</span>Colleen Kirk this too will increase his shoes God give us Christian homes! Homes where the Bible is loved and taught, Homes where the Master’s will is sought, Homes crowned with beauty Your love has wrought; God give
    us Christian homes; God give us Christian homes! God give us Christian homes! Homes where the father is true and strong, Homes that are free from the blight of wrong, Homes that are joyous with love and song; God give us Christian homes; God give
    us Christian homes! God give us Christian homes! will audio policies school but thought office thing this offer still it's still think Rashi idea will</div>
</div>
```

the @media isn't responding as expected.
The first two columns are not fitting into the window when the at 1200px
Same problem is experienced when the window has maximum width of 991px

Comment: `@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991)` You missed 'px' here.

Answer (score 0):

try like this. your mrgin-left:5px is the problem.. so i removed margin-left at 1199px

**css**

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0%;
}
h1{
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
body{
    background-color: aqua;
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
}
.column1{
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-width:2px;
    padding:50px 2px 0px 5px;
    text-align:justify;
    background-color: brown;
}
.column2{
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-width:2px;
    padding:50px 2px 0px 5px;
    text-align:justify;
    background-color: darkslateblue;
}
.column3{
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-width:2px;
    padding:50px 2px 0px 5px;
    text-align:justify;
    background-color: magenta;
}
.column4{
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px #089c2d;
    top:-1px;
    right:-1px;
    width:120px;
    height:40px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}
.row:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    float: left;
}
@media(min-width:1200px){

    .column1{
        float: left;
        width: 33.3%;
    } 
    .column2{
        float: left;
        width: 33.3%;
    } 
    .column3{
        float: left;
        width: 33.3%;
    }    
}
    @media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){
    .column1{float:left; width:50%;}
    .column2{float:left; width:50%;}
    .column3{float:left; width:auto;margin-right: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;}

}
    @media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991){
        .column1{float:left; width:100%;}
        .column2{float:left; width:100%;}
        .column3{float:left; width:100%;}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please notice that you are using margins, and they also need space. Try to use flex (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), or just set block width a little bit smaller (try to use calc).

Answer (score -1):

You're not declaring the unit assigned to the media query: e.g. min-width: 1234**px**.

I also think the use of the @media requires spacing out.

You may have been able to use this previously, so try this:

```
@media (min-width:1234px) {}
```

**I tend to use**:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1234px) {}
```

Then if you wish to go between two sizes:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1234px) and (min-width:4321px) {}
```

I also try to always use the same pixel count for different breakpoints:

```
320px
480px
640px
768px
1024px
1248px
1920px
```

Where your media queries would end one pixel less than the media query that will follow:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 319px) {}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (min-width:479px) {}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (min-width:639px) {}
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (min-width:767px) {}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (min-width:1023px) {}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (min-width:1247px) {}
@media screen and (min-width: 1248px) and (min-width:1979px) {}
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {}
```

Comment: The downvote hurts I will be honest. Have you found your solution?